# Libgdx change the image inside table dynamically

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to draw a HUD that shows the score and time and image like loading but I want to update and change the image when the score get higher but I tried to do that but it is not working. I thought maybe I can define new table in the update method and put different image each time but I don't want to define new table each time. is there anyway to update the image only inside the table:
this is the code:

```
public class Hud implements Disposable{

    public Stage stage;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private static Integer worldTimer;
    private float timecount;
    private static Integer score;
    Label countdownLabel;
    private static Label scorelabel;
    private Label timelabel;
    private Label levellabel;
    private Label worldlabel;
    private Label mariolabel;
    private Image loading;
    private Table table;
    public Hud(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        worldTimer=40;
        timecount=0;
        score=0;
        viewport=new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH,Fruits.V_HIEGT,new OrthographicCamera());//2
        stage=new Stage(viewport,sb);//stage is as box and try to put widget and organize things inside that table
        table = new Table();
        table.top();//table at top of our stage
        table.setFillParent(true);//table is now fill all the stage
        countdownLabel=new Label(String.format("%02d",worldTimer),new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        scorelabel=new Label(String.format("%02d",score),new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        timelabel=new Label("TIME",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        levellabel=new Label("1-1",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        worldlabel=new Label("WORLD",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        mariolabel=new Label("Score"    ,new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
        loading = new Image(new Texture("10%.png"));
        //loading.setSize(40, 10);
        table.add(mariolabel).expandX().padTop(10);

        table.add(timelabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        table.add(worldlabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        table.row();
        table.add(scorelabel).expandX();

        table.add(countdownLabel).expandX();
        table.add(loading).width(50).height(10);

        stage.addActor(table);

    }
    public void update(float dt)
    {
        timecount+=dt;
        if (timecount>1)
        {
            worldTimer--;
            if(worldTimer>=0) {
                countdownLabel.setText(String.format("%02d", worldTimer));
                loading=new Image(new Texture("90.png"));
            }
            timecount=0;

        }
    }
    public static int getTime()
    {

        return worldTimer;
    }

    public static void addScore(int value)
    {
        score +=value;
        scorelabel.setText(String.format("%02d",score));
    }
    public static int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider moving this question to the [game development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You might need to read a bit more about the basics of Java to understand the distinction between objects and references. Reassigning a reference, as you are doing, does not cause anything to happen to the previously referenced object, except possibly making it available for garbage collection.

Comment: but here how can I add the object to the table without creating new table
If I made the creation of table and assigning the object in a method and call it in the update method this will cause creating many tables

Comment: Don't create a new object...change the existing one. First of all, all Texture's should be loaded together in an asset manager class of some kind so you can keep them in one place and make sure you aren't loading multiple of the same one or leaking any of them. (Libgdx has a great AssetManager class you can use for that.) Then apply your the texture to your image as needed. Something like `(TextureRegionDrawable)loading.getDrawable()).setRegion(ninetyPerecentTextureRegion);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load all the texture in your constructor instead of loading them on the fly at runtime. What you are trying to do will be easily achieved in C++ but in Java, one way to do it will be to create an array of table for the textures since that is the only thing you need to update e.g :

```
private Table maintable = new Table();
private Table loading10Table = new Table();
private Table loading90Table = new Table();
private Image loading10 = new Image(new Texture("10%.png"));
private Image loading90 = new Image(new Texture("90%.png"));
```

Add `loading10` to `loading10Table` and `loading90` to `loading90Table` then  add `mainTable` and `loading10Table` to the stage. In the update method, assuming "loading10Table" is was inserted second in the array:

```
stage.getActors()[1] = loading90Table;
```